# Input is not invertible. [[Node: MatrixInverse_2=MatrixInverse[T=DT_FLOAT, adjoint=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add_138)]]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, skflow, gmm

I am trying to implement Gaussian Mixture Model using Tensorflow's tf.learn(skflow) but I am getting the following error.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.factorization.python.ops import gmm as gmm_lib 
import random 
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([[random.random() for i in range(198)] for j in range(2384)], dtype=np.float32) 
gmm = gmm_lib.GMM(128,random_seed=0) 
gmm.fit(x)
```

Error StackTrace :-

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input is not invertible.
     [[Node: MatrixInverse_2 = MatrixInverse[T=DT_FLOAT, adjoint=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add_138)]]
```